# window.matchMedia not works in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, matchmedia

I'm detecting device orientation using `window.matchMedia`. The following code works as intended - every orientation change is logged to console with correct value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Test App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        let isIframe= () => {
            try {
                return window.self !== window.top;
            } catch (e) {
                return true;
            }
        }    

         let onOrientationChange = () => {
            const isLandscape = window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches;
            console.log("Event: " + (isIframe() ? "Iframe " : "") + "landscape:" + isLandscape);
        }

        let mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)");
        
        console.log("Onload: " + (isIframe() ? "Iframe " : "") + "landscape:" + mediaQueryList.matches);

        mediaQueryList.addListener(onOrientationChange);
    </script>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root">Hello World in Iframe</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I run that page in `iframe`, callback registered using `addListener` is not fired. In `iframe`, I only get singular log line - `Onload: Iframe landscape:true`, regardless of the device orientation.

```
 <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root">Hello World</div>
    <iframe id="game" src="iframeContent.html" frameborder="0" style="width: 960px; height: 600px;"></iframe>
  </body>
```

I'm using `addListener` instead of `addEventListener`, because the second one function is not working on all Safari versions.

Tested on Safari 14 and on Dev Tools of Chrome and Firefox.

My question is - why `addListener` callback is not invoked in `iframe`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the iframe does not get it's size to change because it has fixed width and height, thus resize related events cannot be triggered inside it including [`MediaQueryList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) events regarding `orientation`.

You can do two things to get this working; you can make your iFrame width and height to be `100%`, or you can let the media query detection code inside the main window and pass the orientation state using [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) when it triggers a change event.

#### 1) Changing iFrame size to `100%` so it resizes when landscape/portrait orientation event triggers

In the main page, make the body full height and the iframe full width/height (using CSS).

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Live example that you can test: https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/65704468/

#### 2) Media query detection on the main page and use `postMessage` to send a message to iFrame when orientation event triggers

#### `index.html`:

```html
<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
<script>
  let iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

  let onOrientationChange = () => {
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({
      isLandscape: window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches
    }, '*');
  }

  iframe.addEventListener('load', onOrientationChange);

  const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)");

  mediaQueryList.addListener(onOrientationChange);
</script>
```

#### `iframe.html`:

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    if (event.data.isLandscape) {
      console.log('iFrame Landscape');
    } else {
      console.log('iFrame Portrait');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Live example that you can test: https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/65704468/pm/